# Weird Active Admin (Rails) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

This is by far one of the most absurd error's I have come across. I log into active admin and get this on my screen for any active admin page:

(?i-mx:</body>)

I checked out the server logs, and I seem to be logging in successfully, and the server calculates the queries for all the columns but the final output is the above! I am using **ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.1.3 with active admin version 0.4.4**.

This following is a sample log output for one of the page loads:

```
Started GET "/admin/points_logs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-01 09:01:10 -0400
  Processing by Admin::PointsLogsController#index as HTML
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
  AdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (30.9ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `points_logs` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
   (92.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `points_logs` 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `points_logs` 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `points_logs` 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `points_logs` 
  PointsLog Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `points_logs`.* FROM `points_logs` ORDER BY `points_logs`.`id` desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 56 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2654 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 56 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 56 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1122 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 718 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3689 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3689 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 821 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 958 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4708 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 958 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5137 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5137 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5137 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3598 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3598 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5137 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 413 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4324 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4324 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1812 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3726 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1101 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2440 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3369 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3702 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5026 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 684 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1444 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40464 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 29394 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 32958 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 37409 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40463 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40462 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40461 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` =  LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40460 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40459 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40458 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40457 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40454 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` =  LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40452 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40451 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` =  LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40450 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40449 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40448 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40447 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40446 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40445 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40443 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40442 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `transactions`.* FROM `transactions` WHERE `transactions`.`id` = 40441 LIMIT 1
  User Load (278.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
Rendered /Users/bpn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@_1.9.3/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (2594.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3168ms (Views: 2084.9ms | ActiveRecord: 755.6ms)
</p>
```

Comment: Consider adding more code. All you're showing here is that you're querying from the db... but we have no idea what you're doing with the queried object

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto- thanks for your response. I am not doing anything with the queried object- active admin is like an interface to display the db entries. The weird thing is it was working perfectly until I made the switch to Rails 3.1. Has this got something to do with the asset pipeline? or could this be some encoding issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it..It was an issue with my gems namely the rack-mini-profiler. It was such a pain to debug this issue as there was not any particular error messages as such. I reverted back to my previous commits and had to painfully look through all changes to find this!!

Comment: thank god for fast google index. My hat goes off to you for saving me hours of time. did you disable profiler entirely or something?

Comment: ditto- very timely. were you able to track down if this is a bug in Active Admin or in rack-mini-profiler? Its probably a good idea to report this problem to one of the projects

Comment: I just deactivated profiler all together...although the issue did not exist in 0.1.7. I did try opening an issue on rack mini profiler, but did not find the familiar issues tab on github..Do they not have issue tracking setup??

Answer (score 6):

I found a cleaner way to handle this by looking at the [mini-profiler docs](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby) and reviewing the available config options in the [config class](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/blob/master/Ruby/lib/mini_profiler/config.rb)

in a `config/initializers/mini_profiler.rb`

```
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.skip_paths << '/admin' #or whatever you namespace active_admin under
```

side note, there are a couple other useful config settings:

```
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.use_existing_jquery = true
Rack::MiniProfiler.config.pre_authorize_cb = lambda {|env| Rails.env.development?}
```